# Setting Grails port omits application name in link tag

Tags: grails, gsp

If I set `grails.server.port.http = 8080` in BuildConfig or comment it out, link tags work fine.  The tag

```
<g:link action="downloadAsPdf" id="${invoice.id}">
```

is rendered with the URL `http://localhost:8080/Invoicer/invoice/displayAsPdf/2`. This is the correct form because it contains the app-name.

If I then set `grails.server.port.http = 9090`, the same link tag renders with this URL `http://localhost:9090/invoice/displayAsPdf/2`. This URL does not work properly, as it does not include the app name.

I'm able to get around this by setting `grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:9090/${appName}"` in Config.groovy, but this feels not too DRY.  Not only do I have to repeat the port here, but I also have to repeat the format of the base URL. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: If the system is behaving as you described, that is a bug.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we will take a look.

Comment: If you do file an issue, indicate which version of Grails you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffScottBrown.  Issue 9132 created at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9132